# SMART HDD alerts regarding controller

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart

I am getting SMART HDD error's like

```
check_ciss: CRITICAL: Cache status on controller in slot 3 in Temporarily Disabled state
```

Can you guys help me in below queries

1) How did the cache status on controller got disabled ? 
2) is that any thing related to BIOS settinig ?
3) How dose this impact the HDD/system performance ?
4) Is there any good place for learning and understanding about such SMART error messages ?

Comment: Need more information. Operating System? Computer make & model? What are you using this computer for? Events leading up to the error? Did you change anything recently? Etc.etc. etc.

Comment: The operating system i use is RHEL5 and the server model is "HP DL160". This issue i am seeing in multiple servers at times.